# explicit qualification in C++ declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, language-lawyer, qualified-name

The following namespace definition fails to compile when the first declaration is commented out. If the first declaration of `foo` is uncommented, then it compiles just fine.

```
namespace Y
{
    //void foo();
    void ::Y::foo(){}
}
```

The relevant part in the standard (§8.3¶1) says:

> When the declarator-id is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member

I understand that this rule prevents the introduction of names into other namespaces. I wonder if that rule could be relaxed to allow for *qualified-id*s referring to the current namespace.

Comment: To the person who voted for closing because it is unclear what I am asking: The question is already in the text: *Is there any problem if that rule is relaxed to allow for qualified id's referring to the current space?*

Comment: Do you have a valid use-case for this rule-relaxation?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : define "valid" ;-) … the automatic generation of code could benefit if all identifiers could include their scopes. Note that this would be about programs that write programs not necessarily for human consumption.

Comment: That's funny, I actually thought about that;) But I still couldn't come up with a scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**CWG #482**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#482) is relevant:

> According to 8.3 [dcl.meaning] paragraph 1, […] 
>   This restriction prohibits examples like the following:
>
> ```
> void f();
> void ::f();        // error: qualified declarator
>
> namespace N {
>   void f();
>   void N::f() { }  // error: qualified declarator
> }
> ```
>
> There doesn't seem to be any good reason for disallowing such
>   declarations, and a number of implementations accept them in spite of
>   the Standard's prohibition. Should the Standard be changed to allow
>   them?
>
> Notes from the April, 2006 meeting:
>
> **In discussing [issue 548](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#548), the CWG agreed that the prohibition of
>   qualified declarators inside their namespace should be removed.**

So your code is valid if the first declaration of `foo` is present (as of about 2012; GCC has an [open bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64267)). If not, however, your quoted wording still applies and renders the qualified declaration ill-formed. I see no reason to permit that case; it intuitively implies that the name has been declared already, since qualified name lookup must determine what it refers to.