# c++ 1z error: error: explicit qualification in declaration in deduction guide

Tags: c++, c++17

I was trying an example about 1z's deduction guide by using gcc 8.0.0 201706 (Unable to get the code compiled by using clang 5.0.5).

```
namespace std
{

    template<class R, class CLS, class ... ARGS> std::function(R(CLS::*)(ARGS ...)) -> function< R(CLS &, ARGS...)>;
}
```

The compiler complains that

```
error: explicit qualification in declaration of 'std::function(R (CLS::*)(ARGS ...))-> std::function<R(CLS&, ARGS ...)>'
         -> function< R(CLS &, ARGS...)>;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Based on [explicit qualification in C++ declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642510/explicit-qualification-in-c-declaration) the qualification 'std::' should be removed to make the declaration right.

But when I change the deduction guide declaration to (NOTICE the qualification 'std::' is added after '->'). There is no compiler errors:

```
template<class R, class CLS, class ... ARGS> function(R(CLS::*)(ARGS ...))-> std::function< R(CLS &, ARGS...)>;
```

I assume the whole express is a declaration, but it seems the part after '->' is not.

It seems to me that a qualification is able to be used on one part of expression but not the other parts is a bit confusing. Is anyone able to explain the reason behind why the last expression is valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of a *deduction-guide* does not allow qualification on either `function` in your example. The syntax is:

```
deduction-guide:
    explicit(opt) template-name (parameter-declaration-clause) -> simple-template-id;
```

A *template-name* must be an *identifier* (therefore it cannot be a qualified name) and a *simple-template-id* refers to a *template-name* together with its template arguments.

The compiler may still allow redundant qualification as a conforming extension provided that it issues a diagnostic (*i.e.,* a warning). If there is not at least a warning, it is a compiler bug, although I would wait until C++17 is finalized before filing a bug report.